Create Typed Object from Two Arrays in TypeScript
I want to write a method in TypeScript to create an object from an array of keys and an array of values, so that each key/value pair has the type of the value. I have it mostly working:
export type DynamicObjectType<T extends PropertyKey[], J extends unknown[]> =
  { [K in T[number]]: J[number] }

export const twoArraysToObject = <T extends PropertyKey[], J extends unknown[]>(keys: T, values: J): DynamicObjectType<T, J> => (
  keys.reduce((output, input, index) => ({
      ...output,
      [input]: values[index]
    }), {} as DynamicObjectType<T, J>
  ))

const outerCall = <T extends PropertyKey[]>(...keys: T) => <J extends unknown[]>(...values: J) => twoArraysToObject<T, J>(keys, values)

const objectFromArrays = outerCall('a', 'b', 'c')(1, 2, true)

The types on objectFromArrays are :
{
  a: 1 // number | boolean
  b: 2 // number | boolean
  c: true // number | boolean
}

The names, length, and types with be variable (each index will match 1:1, but it may not be these three example values or type).
I think I understand why it works this way, because TypeScript generally interprets an array of mixed types as any element in the array could be any type of any of the elements in the array. In this case however, I want the exact type from the matching index in the array.
I think if I wrote this directly as an array with explicit types, it is interpreting it like this (for example):
const arr: (string | boolean | number)[] = ['a', true, 1]
But I want it to behave like this (for example):
const arr: [string | boolean | number] = ['a', true, 1]
So that the above code results in:
{
  a: 1 // number
  b: 2 // number
  c: true // boolean
}

Using the Functions, Types and Generic I am (or something similar) is there a way to get TypeScript to do what I want?
Thanks!

There's probably a terser solution… but you could use a recursive type to zip the keys/values into a tuple of entries, then map over it to produce the object as shown in this playground. Does that meet your needs? If so, I can write an answer — if not, what did I miss?

I'd say this approach is what you're looking for. See the answer to the linked q/a above for more information.
